# C++ member function as friend

Tags: c++, friend

I have 2 Classes Namely A and B with following independent declaration

```
class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> vec = {B("X","Y")};
public:
    A();
    void clear(std::vector<B>::size_type index);
};

class B {
private:
    std::string m_first;
    std::string m_second;
public:

    B() = default;
    B(std::string first, std::string second) : m_first(first), m_second(second) {}
    
    // I want the friend below - how to do it?
    friend void A::clear(std::vector<B>::size_type index);
};
```

I want to declare `void A::clear(std::vector<B>::size_type index)` to be friend of class B. Is it possible in C++? I cannot do forward declaration of B for A as A needs to see B's constructor with 2 arguments.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't understand your question fully, the edits by UnslanderMonica makes it clear. I've deleted my comments.

Comment: Forward declaration is easy. Just add `class B;` before the line `class A {`

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure that your requirement to have `A::clear` as a friend of `B` is a case of too tight of a coupling. This is friendship misuse. Think of another way of doing it.

Please edit the question and provide the **reason** why you think you need that friendship. What is exactly the relationship between these classes, what's the use case? Convince us that there's a need for friendship, because I don't see it.

And the best I can tell the signature of `B`'s constructor is wasteful in copying the arguments (by taking them by value). These arguments should be taken by const reference, unless you need a copy to modify within the method/constructor. I've fixed it below.

> `A` needs to see `B` constructor with 2 arguments .

It doesn't! `A` doesn't. Only `A`'s constructor does:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class B;

class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> vec;
public:
    A();
    void clear(std::vector<B>::size_type index);
};

class B {
private:
    std::string m_first;
    std::string m_second;
public:

    B() = default;
    B(const std::string &first, const std::string &second) : 
        m_first(first),m_second(second)  {}
    friend void A::clear(std::vector<B>::size_type index);
};

inline A::A() : vec{ B("X", "Y") } {}
```

Another trick is to put `A` inside of `B`. But it's wholly unnecessary.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class B {
private:
    std::string m_first;
    std::string m_second;
public:
    class A {
    private:
        std::vector<B> vec = {B("X","Y")};
    public:
        void clear(const std::vector<B>::size_type &index);
    };

    B() = default;
    B(const std::string &first, const std::string &second) : 
        m_first(first),m_second(second)  {}
    friend void A::clear(const std::vector<B>::size_type &index);
};

using A = B::A;
```

Comment: A is manager of B i.e in program all B entities are managed by A. I can think of 2 ways of doing it . Adding a member function in B to clear it self or use friendship (above).
When you say its friendship misuse , what do you mean ? also isnt that when we define a friendship we actually intend to couple the classes ?

Comment: If `A` wants to manage `B` then `A` should be a friend of `B`. The whole thing, not just one method. But since `B`'s constructors are public, it doesn't look to me like `A` "manages" `B`. Objects that are managed the way you think of have constraints. E.g. you can't put them into vectors (it won't compile) - since `std::vector` knows nothing about using `A` to manage `B`! To state that `A` manages `B` you need to make `B`'s constructors private (or protected). I guess you're coming from Java background?

Comment: In other words, very tight coupling between managers and mangees in C++ can't be done without going all the way. Once `B` constructors are private and only `A` has access to them, then no standard containers can work on `B`. No, making `std::vector<B>` a friend of `B` is not guaranteed to do it (and on many implementations  it doesn't do it). So, instead maybe, think of `A` as a partner of `B`. For example, if `B` wants to inform `A` of its existence, then that can be done differently.

Answer (score 1):

You've set things up so the class `A` needs to be defined before `B` (so `B` can declare a member of `A` as a `friend`) but simultaneously `B` needs to be defined before `A` (so the `vec` member of `A` can be initialised using the constructor of `B`).

This is a circular dependency (definition of `A` must be before definition of `B` which must be before the definition of `A` - ad infinitum).

Declaring a member of a class as a `friend` is not possible unless that class has been previously defined.

You need to break that circular dependency - either by not having `A::clear()` as a `friend` of `B`, or by not initialising the `vec` member of `A` within the class definition (which means you then need to initialise `vec` solely in the constructor of `A`).

Alternatively, it is possible to declare `A` as  `friend` of `B` without `A` being previously defined  (i.e. a previous declaration of `A` is sufficient, without making it a definition).   So an alternative may be to declare `A` as a `friend` of `B` rather than only `A::clear()`.

This means that `B` must be defined before `A`.    `B` can be defined without visibility of the definition of `A`.